# Algo falla en mi buscador en tiempo real

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

es la primera vez que intento hacer un buscador en tiempo real usando listas desplegables como filtro. En Internet no encontré uno que use listas desplegables, así que ando bastante perdido, ya que también es mi primera vez usando este tipo de código, intenté copiar características del buscador tradicional y arreglarme como puede, pero no consigo nada :/
Sé que una pregunta como esta puede llegar a molestar, pero ando muuy perdido, hace poco comencé a programar.

Les dejo mi código.

Página con el "buscador"

```
<div id="buscador">

   <select id="buscar-esto" name="marca">
     <option value="0">Marca</option>
     <?php
         include "../2.inc/actualizar-marca.inc";
     ?>
   </select>

   <select id="buscar-esto" name="categoria">
     <option value="0">Categoría</option>
     <?php
         include "../2.inc/actualizar-categoria.inc";
     ?>
   </select>

   <select id="buscar-esto" name="pais">
     <option value="0">País</option>
     <option value="China">China</option>
     <option value="USA">USA</option>
     <option value="UK">UK</option>
   </select>

</div>
<div id="datos">

</div>
```

ajax.js

```
$(buscar_datos());
function buscar_datos(consulta) {
       $.ajax({
            url: '1.paginas/buscar.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {consulta: consulta},
       })
         .done(function(respuesta) {
           $("#resultado").html(respuesta);
         })
         .fail(function() {
           console.log("error");
         })
}

$(document).on('keyup','#buscar-esto', function(){
   var valor = $(this).val();

    if(valor !=""){
       buscar_datos(valor);
    } else {
      buscar_datos();
    }

});
```

y buscar.php

```
<?php
 $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","minos");

 if (!$conexion) {
     header("Location: error.php?mensaje=No se pudo conectar a la base de datos");
 } else {

$salida ="";
$query = "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER By id";

if(isset($_POST['consulta'])){
  $q = $conexion ->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
  $query = "SELECT id, descri, precio, marca, catego, pais, imagen FROM productos
  WHERE marca LIKE '%".$q."%' OR categoria LIKE '%".$q."%' OR pais LIKE '%".$q."%'";

 }

 $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
 if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
   $salida.= "<table class='tabla_datos'>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>id</td> <td>descri</td> <td>precio</td><td>marca</td><td>catego</td> 
                        <td>pais</td><td>imagen</td>                
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>";
      while($fila =$resultado->fetch_assoc() ){
        $salida.= "<tr>
                <td>".$fila['id']."</td><td>".$fila['descri']."</td><td>".$fila['descri']."</td> 
                <td>".$fila['precio']."</td><td>".$fila['marca']."</td><td>".$fila['catego']."</td> 
                <td>".$fila['pais']."</td> <td>".$fila['imagen']."</td>           
        </tr>";
}
  $salida.="</tbody></table>";
} else {
   $salida.="No hay datos :()";
}
  echo "$salida";
  mysqli_close($conexion);

}

  ?>
```

Comment: Primero debes sustituir los `id` de los `select` ya que deben ser únicos

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [No funciona mi buscador en tiempo real](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336542/no-funciona-mi-buscador-en-tiempo-real)

Comment: totalmente, gracias.