# No funciona mi buscador en tiempo real

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

ya hace unas cuantas horas vengo intentando hacer que me funcione un buscador en tiempo real, y por más que busque tutoriales en internet, no logro hacer que funcione, no encuentro la falla en mi código y ya estoy desesperado. Quizá ustedes podrían ayudarme.Cuando me dirijo a la pagina "buscar.php" me salen todos los datos de mi tabla, pero como que no interviene el código que escribi en "ajax.js".

agregué con un script una librería y obviamente otro script con la ubicacion de la carpeta "ajax.js".

Consultas.php

```
<selection class="principal">
   <div class="form-1-2">
     <label for="caja_busqueda">Buscar:</label>
     <input type="text" name="caja_busqueda" id="caja_busqueda" placeholder="Buscar...">
   </div>

<div id="datos"> </div>

</selection>
```

ajax.js

```
$(buscar_datos());

function buscar_datos(consulta) {

  $.ajax({
    url: '1.paginas/buscar.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'php',
    data: {consulta: consulta},

    })
    .done(function(respuesta) {
      $("#datos").php(respuesta);
    })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("error");
    })
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#caja_busqueda',function() {
     var valor = $(this).val();
     if(valor != ""){
       buscar_datos(valor);
     } else {
       buscar_datos();
     }
});
```

buscar.php

```
<?php
 $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","minos");


$salida= "";
$query = "SELECT * FROM productos ORDER By id";

if (isset($_POST['consulta'])) {
  $q = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
  $query = "SELECT id, descri, precio, marca, catego, pais, imagen FROM productos
  WHERE marca LIKE '%".$q."%' OR catego LIKE '%".$q."%' OR pais LIKE '%".$q."%'";
}

$resultado = $mysqli->query($query);

if($resultado->num_rows > 0){

     $salida.="<table class='tabla_datos'>
                 <thead>
                      <tr>
                           <td>id</td>
                           <td>descri</td>
                           <td>precio</td>
                           <td>marca</td>
                           <td>catego</td>
                           <td>pais</td>
                           <td>imagen</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>";
   while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
     $salida.=" <tr>
                  <td>".$fila['id']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['descri']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['precio']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['marca']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['catego']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['pais']."</td>
                  <td>".$fila['imagen']."</td>
                </tr>";
   }
   $salida.="</tbody></table>";
} else {
   $salida.="No hay datos :c";
}

echo "$salida";

$mysqli->close();

  ?>
```

Comment: El código de `ajax.php` tienes que ponerlo en `Consultas.php` Primeramente, ese es código del cliente (Javascript/Ajax), no del servidor, por lo tanto, no tiene ningún sentido tenerlo en un archivo PHP aparte. Segundo, si observas el código, éste escucha los `keyup` del elemento `caja_busqueda`. Si no esta integrado donde están esos elementos jamás funcionará. Entonces dirás, ¿cómo hace Ajax entonces para buscar los datos en el servidor? Pues la magia está en el archivo que pones en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax, es ese archivo el que busca los datos en el servidor.

Comment: muchísimas gracias.